# Spivak Calculus Chapter 5 (Limits) Problem 3 Part (i)

Tags: calculus, limits, proof-verification

The question is: Find a $\delta$ such that $|f(x)-l|<\epsilon$ for all $x$ satisfying 0 < $|x-a|$<$\delta$.

(i) $f(x)=x^4; l=a^4$

This was my attempt, but I am lacking confidence in every single attempt of Spivak's exercises because I feel I not as rigorous as Spivak wants me to be.:

$|x^4-a^4|<\epsilon\\|x^4|-|a^4|<\epsilon\\|x|-|a|<\frac{\epsilon}{(|x|+|a|)\cdot (|x|^2+|a|^2)}$

So, $\delta=\frac{\epsilon}{(|x|+|a|)\cdot (|x|^2+|a|^2)}$

$\because |x-a|<\frac{\epsilon}{(|x|+|a|)\cdot (|x|^2+|a|^2)} \implies |x|-|a|<\frac{\epsilon}{(|x|+|a|)\cdot (|x|^2+|a|^2)}$

It feels correct to me but at the same time I have almost no confidence in my solution. (I'm trying to self-study the book after taking Calc I-III)

Comment: There are a collection of tricks to learn and then you will spot patterns. Do not be intimidated. A standard trick is $x^4-a^4 = (x^2-a^2)(x^2+a^2)$. Repeating gets a factor of $x-a$ and then you need more tricks to bound the parameters so you can get the limit you want. The difficulty that people have is that there is too much freedom and not enough guidance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The delta you get cannot depend on $x$. We wish to find $\delta$ such that
$$
0 < |x-a|<\delta\implies |x^4-a^4|<\epsilon
$$ 
First we do scratch work to determine a $\delta$. Note that
$$
|x^4-a^4|=|x-a||x+a||x^2+a^2|\tag{1}.
$$
We wish to bound $|x^4-a^4|$ by controlling $|x-a|$. Thus we need to find a bound for $|x+a||x^2+a^2|$ when $x$ is near $a$. To do this, take $0<|x-a|<1$ (for example). Then
$$
|x+a|\leq |x-a|+|2a|<1+2|a|\tag{2}
$$
and
$$
|x^2+a^2|\leq |x^2-a^2|+2a^2=|x-a||x+a|+2a^2<1+2|a|+2a^2\tag{3}
$$
by (2). Hence take
$$
\delta=\min\left(1,\frac{\epsilon}{(1+2|a|)(1+2|a|+2a^21+2|a|+2a^2)}\right).\tag{4}
$$

Comment: this is an incredibly intuitive explanation. Is the choice of 1 in |x-a|<1 entirely arbitrary?

Comment: @chittychitty Yes. I could choose 42.

Answer (score 3):

$$\lim_\limits{x\to a}x^4=a^4$$
Suppose an arbitrary $\varepsilon>0$ is given. We are required to find a $\delta>0$ such that
$$|x^4-a^4|<\varepsilon\Longleftarrow|x-a|<\delta$$

Let $\delta=1$
$$\begin{align}|x-a|&<1\\-1<x-a&<1\\2a-1<x+a&<2a+1\\|x+a|&<2|a|+1\end{align}$$

And we know that

$$\begin{align}|x|&=|x-a+a|\\|x|&\le|x-a|+|a|\\|x|-|a|&\le|x-a|\\|x|-|a|&\le1\\|x|^2&\le(|a|+1)^2\\x^2+a^2=|x^2+a^2|&\le(|a|+1)^2+a^2\end{align}$$

Getting back to the problem...

$$\begin{align}|x^4-a^4|&=|(x^2+a^2)(x+a)(x-a)|\\|x^4-a^4|&\le(x^2+a^2)|x+a||x-a|\\|x^4-a^4|&\le\left\{(|a|+1)^2+a^2\right\}(2|a|+1)\end{align}$$

Choosing $\delta=\min\left\{1,\dfrac{\varepsilon}{\left\{(|a|+1)^2+a^2\right\}(2|a|+1)}\right\}$ completes the proof.

Comment: You missed  |x-a| on  the right side of your last inequality.

Comment: @MohammadRiazi-Kermani it is equal to 1, from a previous assumption.

Answer (score 0):

An even easier approach is suggested by the proof of the lemma of Theorem 2, part 2, from earlier in the chapter:

If $|x-x_0| < \min(1, \frac{\epsilon}{2(|y_0|+1)})$ and $|y-y_0| < \frac{\epsilon}{2(|x_0|+1)}$, then $|xy - x_0y_0| < {\epsilon}$

In this case, you have:

$f(x)=x^4; l=a^4$

Substituting $x^2$ in for both $x$ and $y$ and $a^2$ in for both $x_0$ and $y_0$, we see that $|x^4 - a^4| = |(x^2)(x^2) - (a^2)(a^2)| < {\epsilon}$ as long as ${\delta} = \min(1, \frac{\epsilon}{2(|a^2|+1)})$